# How to apply a filter with multiple options

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this object that I am trying to apply filter using LINQ in C#, and I just curious how can I apply this.

```
public class glAccts
{
   public string fund {get;set;}
   public string location {get;set;}
   public string costCenter {get;set;}
   public string object {get;set;}
}
```

What I want to do is be able is have method like follow

```
public async TaskIEnumerable<<glAccts>> applyFilter(IEnumerable<glAccts> filterList)
{
   ... code to fetch a list of all glAccts -- glUserAccess --...
               if (filteredGL.Count() > 0)
        {
            for( int i = 0; i < filteredGL.Count(); i++ )
            {
                if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filteredGL.ElementAt(i).fund)) {
                    var response = glUserAccess.Where(c => c.fund.Contains(filteredGL.ElementAt(i).fund));
                }
                if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filteredGL.ElementAt(i).location)) {
                    var response = glUserAccess.Where(c => c.location.Contains(filteredGL.ElementAt(i).location));
                }
                if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filteredGL.ElementAt(i).costCenter)) {
                    var response = glUserAccess.Where(c => c.costCenter.Contains(filteredGL.ElementAt(i).costCenter));
                }
                if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filteredGL.ElementAt(i).objects)) {
                    var response = glUserAccess.Where(c => c.objects.Contains(filteredGL.ElementAt(i).objects));
                }

            }
        }

}
```

Note: this is what I currently have, however I am unsure on how to merge my response, and what if my object is blank. I am also assuming there might be an easier way doing with LINQ.

What I would like to do is construct something like this:

```
SELECT glAccts WHERE (activeGlAccts.fund == filteredList[i].fund AND activeGlAccts.location == filteredList[i].location activeGlAccts.costCenter == filteredList[i].costCenter AND activeGlAccts.object == filteredList[i].object ) OR (activeGlAccts.fund == filteredList[i].fund AND activeGlAccts.location == filteredList[i].location activeGlAccts.costCenter == filteredList[i].costCenter AND activeGlAccts.object == filteredList[i].object )
```

Notice: There would be an OR between each filtered option and each element would be group by AND

Comment: both `or` clauses  of your `where` are exactly the same (in the one-liner last code fragment)

Comment: I guess what I am trying to say, is for each IEnumerable filteredApply it would not grab the previous fund, location, costCenter and object. I not familiar with SQL query anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public async TaskIEnumerable<glAccts> applyFilter(IEnumerable<glAccts> filterList)
{
   //... code to fetch a list of all glAccts -- glUserAccess --...
    var response = glUserAccess.Where(c => 
        filteredGL.Any(x=>
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.fund) || c.fund.Contains(x.fund)) && 
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.location) || c.location.Contains(x.location)) && 
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.costCenter) || c.costCenter.Contains(x.costCenter)) && 
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.objects) || c.objects.Contains(x.objects))
            )
        );
    //... rest of code
}
```

Comment: It almost work, what your doing make sense but it only grab the first filteredgl element, not the second or third one. I think x.fund and x.location only grab the first filteredGl and  now each of them. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Jseb aren't you trying to filter the glUserAcess? Its elements that will be returned, not the ones from filteredGL. For each glUserAcess element, the code evaluates the entire filteredGL searching for a match, if one is found, the item is kept, otherwise it is discarted.

Comment: sorry I am testing, I think just found that the second element wasn't part of my original list, so your code is correct, thank you.